# Fractal square partition

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, fractals

Consider the following sequence:

[image: matrix]

the next are c), d) and so on. Let's assume that p1=0.2, p2=0.5, p3=0.2, p4=0.1.

The question is: how to obtain (not necessarily graphically illustrated in example a) and b) ) a matrix of numbers with successive results for parameter q, where q is the number of steps (in case of a) q = 1, in case b) q = 2 , in case c) q = 3, etc.

As a consequence we should get (I think in step q = 8) a graph like 'Model III (right plot)' shown here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_cascade

ralph

Comment: The pictures in your link to multiplicative cascade are done with a multiplicative random process, so they are different from the deterministic method in this question.

Answer (score 11):

It appears that you are looking for the Kronecker product.

```
q1 = {{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}};
q2 = KroneckerProduct[q1, q1];
q2 // MatrixForm
```

[image: Kronecker product]

For the next step:

```
KroneckerProduct[q1, q2]
```

To do this in general, set up a recursion:

```
kprod[1] = {{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}};
kprod[n_] := kprod[n] = KroneckerProduct[kprod[1], kprod[n - 1]];
```

and so

```
kprod[3] // MatrixForm
```

gives the third term.

---

It might also be worth mentioning that these matrices can be used to model certain [multi-fractal measures](http://rudolf.riedi.home.hefr.ch/Publ/PDF/intro.pdf) - especially, since the post has the [fractals](/questions/tagged/fractals) tag. We can visualize this measure like so:

```
MatrixPlot[kprod[8] /. {p1 -> 0.2, p2 -> 0.5, p3 -> 0.2, p4 -> 0.1},
           Frame -> False]
```

[image: multi-fractal measure]

Comment: @Marc McClure thanks for the visualization!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend *not* computing the matrix symbolically as bill s illustrated, then replacing, but operating upon your numeric matrix directly.  You might also consider using [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) or [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) in place of recursion.

```
prods[m_?MatrixQ, n_Integer] := NestList[KroneckerProduct[m, #] &, m, n - 1]

prods[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}}, 5] === Array[kprod, 5]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

But also critically:

```
prods[{{0.2, 0.5}, {0.2, 0.1}}, 13]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.324644, Null}
> ```

(Don't try this with `kprod` unless you want to hang your machine.)